# Team Foundation Server (TFS) File Difference viewer - customize with other tool

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, diff

I am using Team Foundation Server (TFS) for Visual Studio 2005.

Whenever i wish to compare two file's versions TFS displays a window with the differences.

**The problem is that it is always split vertically.**

In fact, almost every time, **i would prefer to have it split horizontally.**
I've already looked at TFS options and googled but i found nothing. I'm appalled to think that such option is not available!

Is there any way to configure TFS to split it horizontally?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've found the built in differencing tool in TFS woefully lacking so I set up WinMerge (http://www.winmerge.org/) in my environment in Tools -> Options -> Source COntrol -> Visual Studio Team Foundation.

A nice blog post exists below:

http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2007/12/Better-DiffMerge-tool-for-TFS.aspx

Comment: Here is another nice detailed blog showing how to setup and use WinMerge in VS: http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/

Comment: Thank you for your contribution

Comment: The link in the answer is broken, but @RayVega's link worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

There is no ability to change the orientation of the built-in diff/merge utility. There are a lot of third-party tools (some free, some not) to choose from. Check out this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/pages/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) from James Manning where he tracks the correct command/argument values to use when configuring various tools for use by Team Foundation's compare and (content) merge operations.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a more thorough description of how to use Winmerge in TFS- http://www.neovolve.com/post/2007/06/19/using-winmerge-with-tfs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio 2012 and I get to choose between side - by - side options and inline mode. With inline mode, the before and after appear one below the other so that I have the full window for editing.

[Related post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316799/visual-studio-2012-code-review-difference-window)

Answer (score 0):

To use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) ([on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/) as well), you have to navigate to **Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server** (Visual Studio 2015; other versions may have this option in slightly different places). On that Option page, select **Configure User Tools...** and in that dialog, select **Add...** to add the information for your diff tool.

In the "Configure Tool" dialog, I have set the following information:

- Extension: `.*`
- Operation: `Compare` (or `Merge` if you want)
- Command: Path to `WinMergeU.exe`
- [Arguments](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html): `/x /e /u /wl /wr /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2`

Comment: I posted this answer because the [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190722/393280) just contained links to the content.