# Using different software to diff on TFS files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Team Foundation Server (TFS) File Difference viewer - customize with other tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188166/team-foundation-server-tfs-file-difference-viewer-customize-with-other-tool)

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with TFS. I don't like the default diff program of TFS.

Is it possible to change default diff program to something else, like WinMerge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use just about any 3rd party merge tool with TFS. [Here is a Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) with comprehensive instructions on calling out to most of the major diff / merge tools.

Comment: James Manning's post is the best, I strongly encourage you people to use a Merge tool that handles three way merge, so stay away from Winmerge which can't do that. Go for KDiff3 (effective, free, but ugly) or BeyondCompare (the best but not free).

Comment: @Nockawa, I agree that a tool that supports 3 way merges is very useful. SouceGear's DiffMerge is Free (as in beer) and supports 3 way merges. I use a combination of DiffMerge and WinMerge, as diffmerge doesn't support binary comparisons.

Comment: Pre VS11, I used WinMerge for Diff'ing and KDiff for merging... go figure :)