# Visual Studio Code Review Difference Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I was doing C# code reviews at first in VS 2012 I was getting a side by side comparison of the old and new code.
However now I am getting all code in the same window with red lines for old code and green lines for new code.
I cannot find the option to change this back to a difference window.
I know this is a simple issue but any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There should be a button on the toolbar like this one that will let you select the 4 different "diff modes".

[image]

You can also use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- `Ctrl+\`, `Ctrl 1` - Inline
- `Ctrl+\`, `Ctrl 2` - Side-by-side
- `Ctrl+\`, `Ctrl 3` - Left Only
- `Ctrl+\`, `Ctrl 4` - Right Only

to change the view.

Comment: so silly and funny, I may have accidentally clicked it to right only,  and I was seeing the, _thus, lopsided_ version of `Compare with Unmodified...` option in Visual Studio for _**weeks**_ !!!

Answer (score 10):

Below screenshot will help in setting the option to compare side by side.

[image: Side by side mode]

Comment: How does this provide anything more than the accepted answer from over two years before?